# asp.net mvc4, jquery mobile: jquery/javascript function to trap changing of one view to another on the browser

Tags: jquery-mobile, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 3 different views sharing the same master page (_layout.vbhtml).

In each view, the user has to select different list-items. I am using sessionStorage to store the selected values. Then, on each view change, I would like to post those values back to the server. To achieve this, I am adding the following at the end of each view:

```
      $(window).unload(function () {
        alert("Bye now!");
        postjson();
      });
```

But, it is not working as expected. The user can click different buttons to navigate away from the page, but on button click, should not the window unload and fire the alert message? No, it's not doing that.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
alert("Bye now!");
        postjson();
      });
```

Comment: Already tried that, sorry, forgot to mention in my original post.

Comment: try this $(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){ and also check that there is no errors on page and jquery file is properly loading

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either. It must be something with the mvc4 framework. It only fires when I close down the tab or window.

Comment: It has nothing to do with mvc 4. it should work your function should be in document.ready

Comment: Tassadaque, read this http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/api/events.html. With jQuery mobile you are recommended to use pageinit, not document.ready.

Answer (score 0):

> Probably too late to answer

With views sharing the same layout when the user moves away from the a view to another view he/she does not `navigate away` **from** the view. You should use the jquery mobile [events](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html)

using `pagebeforehide` or `pagehide` will do for you. here a excerpt from the docs

**pagebeforehide**

> Triggered on the "fromPage" we are transitioning away
>   from, before the actual transition animation is kicked off. Callbacks
>   for this event will receive a data object as their 2nd arg. This data
>   object has the following properties on it:
>
> ```
>     nextPage (object)
>         A jQuery collection object that contains the page DOM element that we are transitioning to.
>
> Note that this event will not be dispatched during the transition of the first page >     at application startup since there is no previously active page.
> ```

**pagehide**

> Triggered on the "fromPage" after the transition animation has
>   completed. Callbacks for this event will receive a data object as
>   their 2nd arg. This data object has the following properties on it:
>
> ```
>     nextPage (object)
>         A jQuery collection object that contains the page DOM element that we just transitioned to.
>
> Note that this event will not be dispatched during the transition of the first page at application startup since there is no previously
> ```
>
> active page.
>
> You can access the prevPage or nextPage properties via the second
>   argument of a bound callback function.

Comment: Calling them on $(document) or $('div') doesn't work as expected. Do you know how to call them? Thanks for your reply.